# Is the ring of formal power series in any sort of completion of $\mathbb Q(x)$?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, power-series

This question should be a real soft-ball for any serious algebraist.

So, $\mathbb Q(x)$ obviously contains all polynomials, but also things like $1/(1 - x)$. Now my question is this: Can we make sense of the equation
$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} x^n = \frac{1}{1 - x}
$$
in any extension field of $\mathbb Q(x)$, for instance one that contains $\mathbb Q[[x]]$? What about $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb Q$?

The trouble is that the fraction field of $\mathbb Q[[x]]$ (EDIT: <s>does not seem to make said identity valid</s> is actually the solution, see the answer below). Now one could try to argue from the "real" theorem by identifying expressions that on some open subset of $\mathbb R$ yield the same value, but this approach would fail over different fields where there is no obvious embedding into $\mathbb R$.

Also, in the surreal numbers (or larger ordered fields contained therein), the statement does not quite seem true, because there the notion of convergence is incredibly strong.

Comment: If $\Bbb Q(x)$ is the completion of anything it seems like it should be the completion of $\Bbb Q[x]$, the ring of polynomials...

Comment: Or perhaps of $\mathbb Z[x]$, by the same logic?

Comment: there's no actual "logic" here until we _define_ exactly what sort of completion we mean. but no, speaking vaguely, it seems like something in the completion of $\Bbb Z[x]$ "should" be a power series _with integer coefficients_...

Comment: $\mathbb Q(x)$, however, is not a power series ring...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are after is the field of [formal Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_Laurent_series) over $\mathbb Q$, usually denoted $\mathbb Q((x))$. It is the fraction field of $\mathbb Q[[x]]$, and contrary to what you mention, the identity $\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ does hold there - indeed, this simply amounts to checking that $(1-x)\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n=1$, which you can do by considering each coefficient.

Relatedly to the question in the title, $\mathbb Q((x))$ actually is a completion of $\mathbb Q(x)$ in the same way as $\mathbb Q[[x]]$ is a completion of $\mathbb Q[x]$. The metric is defined as follows: for any two distinct $f,g\in\mathbb Q(x)$, write $f-g=x^n\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q$ polynomials not divisible by $x$, and define $d(f,g)=2^{-n}$. This construction is very similar to the construction of $p$-adic numbers (and, indeed, we can call $\mathbb Q((x))$ the $x$-adic completion of $\mathbb Q(x)$.

Lastly, regarding surreal numbers - you are correct the identity is not true, but this is because the sum in question is not convergent for any $x\neq 0$ (indeed, no sequence of surreals converges unless it is eventually constant.)

Comment: Well, actually... In surreal numbers, there is a notion of formal summation whereby the identity $\sum \limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \varepsilon^n=\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}$ holds for any infinitesimal number $\varepsilon$. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hahn_series under "Summable families".

Comment: @nombre I'm afraid I do not see in the linked article any mention of "formal summation" for surreals.

Comment: Indeed. Conway showed that the field of surreal numbers is a Hahn series field (modulo allowing proper classes as value groups). And the family $(\varepsilon^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is summable for any infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ in such field, by a result of Bernhard Neumann. In any case, this was just an aside.